# Sending an automatic email from Excel when a cell reaches a value that will increase

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an excel worksheet which I have already got a change event and module set up to automatically send and email when a cell reaches a certain value in one column.

I need to set up a new change event and I assume module for a different column to generate an automatic email when the value reaches a certain figure.  My problem is this figure will always be increasing, and i  need the email to be sent once the column reaches every +300 from the previous email sent.  ie if the email is sent when the value reaches 1904, i need it to then send when it reaches 2204, then 2504 and so on.

I've tried changing some codes from examples but it doesn't seem to be working.  I don't really know how to write the codes so assistance would be appreciated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 204 Then
    If Target.Value Mod 300 = 0 Then
        Call EngineHoursW01T
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Module -

```
Sub EngineHoursW01T()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Please service Pump" & vbNewLine & _
              "" & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & _
              "xxxx"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Service of Pump"
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add ("")
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

   Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I would add a new worksheet to persist information about notifications and the trigger values. That way, you can check the most recent notification event to determine whether the new value is more than 300 from the previous value.

Comment: Can you describe what's happening/not happening?

Comment: @AlexK. nothing is happening, ie no email is being generated, which i'm assuming i've got an error in either my change event or module.  I don't know enough about writing vba codes to figure it out.

Comment: @andy holaday - i'm sorry, you've lost me completely.  I have 8 worksheets in my workbook and each worksheet needs the event to run

Comment: The Mod 300 will only trigger if Target.Value / 300 has no remainder (so 300,600,900 ...) is that what you want? If not you will need to store the value that triggered the *last* email send (in a hidden sheet or getsetting/savesetting)

Comment: what does no remainder mean?  i want it to trigger every 300 however it may not be a specific 300 that is entered so maybe a range of 290 - 310?  I'm not sure what a hidden sheet or getsetting/savesetting is - sorry

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a simplified approach. The problem we want to solve is: Send an email when the value of "X" has grown by 300 or more since the last email was sent.

Question 1: How do we know what value of "X" was present when the last email was sent?

Answer 1: We need to store the values of "X" each time an email is sent and save these values for future reference. In Excel the natural way to save a value that can be retrieved later is to store it in a worksheet. Let's call it `LogSheet`.

Question 2: Now I am checking new values and I have "Z". Should I send an email?

Answer 2: We consult `LogSheet` and find the last value that triggered an email. Is `Z > 300 + X`? If so, we send a new email and append "Z" to `LogSheet`. If not, we ignore it.

Question 3: How can I track 8 entity results independently?

Answer 3: Extend the logic above.

At each step you will need to write code. I suggest you tackle these in order, and create new questions if you get stuck.